# How to disable and Enable TextBox acording to checklbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="htmlChkNotify" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleTextBox(this,'htmlTxtNotifyemailaddress')" />  
<asp:TextBox ID="htmlTxtNotifyemailaddress" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

function ToggleTextBox(CheckBox, TextBoxID) {

```
     var TextBox = document.getElementById(TextBoxID);  
     if (CheckBox.checked) {  
         TextBox.disabled = false;  
         TextBox.value = "";  
     }  
     else {  
         TextBox.disabled = true;  
         TextBox.value = "";  
     }  
 }
```

I have write like but when I run the code then error message comeing " can't be pass this literal" something like that, so how can I do it?

Actually u can also see demo in stackoverflow "Notify daily of any new answers" I want to fire event like.

Thank you

Comment: The exact error message would probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OnCheckChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged.aspx) is expecting an ASP.Net event handler, it's not for JavaScript, for that attach your event handler like this:

```
htmlChkNotify.Attributes.Add("onclick",  
   "ToggleTextBox(this,'" + htmlTxtNotifyemailaddress.ClientID + "');");
```

I broke it down to 2 lines for readability here only, but the idea is to generate an `onclick` inline handler, rather than the server-side event handler it's currently trying to bind, in a place it can't pass `this` (which is why the parser fails).

Comment: I have dons same as u told but javascript function is not firing and not giving any error.

Comment: @Nishant - what does your rendered version look like now?